# How do I use multiprocessing to speed up a 3D integhration?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a 3D dataset that I am trying to integrate over. This is the code below that I'm trying to use (with data as just some random 3D array here). The data is in Cartesian coordinates, and I want to conver to cylindrical coordinates and then integrate in azimuth to produce r vs z

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nr
from scipy import interpolate as spi

nxt = 120
nyt = 120
nzt = 60
xmint = -0.48e-3
xmaxt = 0.48e-3
ymint = -0.48e-3
ymaxt = 0.48e-3
zmint = -0.48e-3
zmaxt = 0.48e-3
xb = np.linspace(xmint, xmaxt, nxt)
yb = np.linspace(ymint, ymaxt, nyt)
zb = np.linspace(zmint, zmaxt, nzt) 

data = nr.rand(nxt, nyt, nzt) #just random numbers here for example
interp = spi.RegularGridInterpolator(xb, yb, zb, data) #setting up interpolation

r = np.linspace(0, np.max(xb), 100)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
dphi = phi[1]-phi[0]

integ_array = np.zeros((np.size(r), np.size(phi))

for iz, zval in enumerate(zb):
    for ir, rval in enumerate(r):
        for iphi, phival in enumerate(phi):
            interp_val = interp([rval*np.cos(phival),rval*np.sin(phival),zval])
            integ_array[ir,iz] += interp_val*dphi/(2*np.pi)
```

This code is correct, and produces the correct values, but it is obviously slow to run (due to the triple for loop). I'd like to try to use some method to speed this up. `numba` does not work as I am using the `scipy` library to perform the interpolation. Someone suggested using `multiprocessing`. My attempt to do that is below:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nr
from scipy import interpolate as spi
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import itertools

def f(x):
    r_ind = x[0]
    phi_ind = x[1]
    z_ind = x[2]
    xval = r[r_ind]*np.cos(phi[phi_ind])
    yval = r[r_ind]*np.sin(phi[phi_ind])
    zval = z[z_ind]
    interp_val = interp([xval, yval, zval])
    integ_array[r_ind, z_ind] += interp_val * dphi/(2*np.pi)
    return 
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    nxt = 120 
    nyt = 120 
    nzt = 60 
    xmint = -0.48e-3
    xmaxt = 0.48e-3
    ymint = -0.48e-3
    ymaxt = 0.48e-3
    zmint = -0.48e-3
    zmaxt = 0.48e-3
    xb = np.linspace(xmint, xmaxt, nxt)
    yb = np.linspace(ymint, ymaxt, nyt)
    zb = np.linspace(zmint, zmaxt, nzt) 
    data = nr.rand(nxt, nyt, nzt) #just random numbers here for example
    interp = spi.RegularGridInterpolator(xb, yb, zb, data) #setting up interpolation

    r = np.linspace(0, np.max(xb), 100)
    phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    dphi = phi[1]-phi[0]

    integ_array = np.zeros((np.size(r), np.size(zb))
    
    r_indices = [i for i in range(len(r))]
    phi_indices = [i for i in range(len(phi))]
    z_indices = [i for i in range(len(zb))]
    combo_list = [r_indices, phi_indices, z_indices]
    perms = [p for p in itertools.product(*combo_list)]

    with Pool() as pool: 
        pool.map(f, perms)
```

However, when I check `integ_array` after this, it just seems to be an array entirely filled with zeros and I'm not sure why. I'm completely new to `multiprocessing` so any advice on what I'm doing wrong here would be fantastic